# Evisa for Georgia for an Indian citizen

Tags: europe, international-travel, eu, georgia-country

The evisa website for Georgia says that a decision for a visa will get given in 5 working days on my email. I got a payment confirmation on Monday but no mail after that and it's Saturday now. Anyone else tried the evisa portal and had to wait longer?

Comment: Maybe Monday didn't count, and you should count from Tuesday, why don't you wait until next Monday?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is experiencing so called 'post-submission' anxiety. Please wait for a few more days and ask to reopen if you still don't have a visa.